# How can Kaspersky embed code into web page accessed via HTTPs?

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, kaspersky

I have `Kaspersky Internet Security` (antivirus program) doing some security for me. Specifically, it checks links by it's database and marking it with green `K` signs.

The question is: how it can be done if protocol is HTTPs and no any extensions installed in Chrome?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Some additional info on certificates is below. Looks like certificates are issued by KIS and it is accepted silently. Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can `Kaspersky Internet Security`, alter encrypted http traffic, only if you enable the feature which allows it to "secure" encrypted http traffic.  I cannot say one way or another if `Kaspersky Internet Security` actually does alter encrypted http traffic because I don't enable security features that break encrypted secure http connections with websites.  In other words...if you are worried, disable the feature that allows `Kaspersky Internet Security`  to "secure" encrypted connections and then you don't have to worry about it altering the traffic.

Comment: Can you share the certificate information for that website you're showing in the screenshot? (Click on the green lock in the address bar and select "Certificate Information")

Comment: @Ramhound what I am worrying about is the general ability to sniff encrypted traffic by simply clicking some check box. If `KIS` can do this, then any other application also can. Some other application can be not so polite as `KIS` and can forget to ask my permission to sniff and could sniff silently.

Comment: No; KIS because your using it as a proxy, and have configure your browsers to use KIS, thus allowing KIS to intercept all HTTPS traffic.  Provide the certificate information as requested

Comment: @Ramhound I am not using KIS as a proxy.

Comment: @heavyd it's Google, link is on screenshot

Comment: @Dims, I can see what's in the address bar, I'd like to see the certificate information like I originally requested.  That will tell us if Kaspersky is intercepting traffic before or after it leaves the browser.

Comment: @heavyd sorry, see my update please

Comment: Yes you are because the google certificate is signed by Kaspersky instead of google.....as I said disable that security feature if you are worried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from your updated certificate information, even though you are visiting `https://www.google.ru`, the certificate is Issued by "Kaspersky Anti-Virus Personal Root Certificate."

What this means is that the Kaspersky is intercepting your SSL/TLS connections and generating a certificate on the fly to impersonate the real website you're visiting.  They can do this because they have installed a Certificate Authority certificate in the certificate store on your machine.

Comment: How to control this by the means not involving `KIS` itself?

Comment: i.e. can I revoke permission somehow?

Comment: What? Please clarify your comment.  disable the option in KIS or place the KIS CA in the untrusted certificate store, or do the correct thing don't use any security product with a feature like this because their CA will be compromised as Lenovo as proven and thus proxy CA security features cannot be trusted at all

Comment: As @Ramhound mentioned earlier, if you want to disable this feature you need to disable it in the Kaspersky settings (http://support.kaspersky.com/6271)

Comment: For clear testing, I wish to try to disable the feature by means of browser, `OS` but not `KIS`. On the other hand, I don't need to disable it completely, because I wish (or may wish) to virus-check HTTPs traffic too.

Comment: @Ramhound how to place KIS CA in the untrusted certificate store?

Comment: @Dims, placing the certificate in the untrusted store will just make all HTTPS sites appear to to be untrusted and completely unusable.

Comment: You cannot have it both ways.  If the CA is not installed or not trusted., KIS will be unable to spy on you, if it's enable you risk KIS spying on you.  If untrusted you also have to confirm a certificate error on every secure connection, how you do that, is documented well so that is a learning task for you

Comment: Also, to add to @Ramhound 's answer, even if you do confirm a certificate error on every request, KIS will still be intercepting your requests.  If you want to disable this, you must do it through KIS.

Comment: @Ramhound this is what I wish to check: do something and ensure that KIS is unable to spy anymore.

Comment: If the option is enabled KIS will spy on you.

Comment: @heavyd I don't understand, why HTTPs is not working then; what is it protecting, if I can't disconnect insistent spy? the protection is nonsense if is is rely on the malicious agent politeness!

Comment: @Ramhound what is the purpose of HTTPs then? to protect from those persons, who obey options?

Comment: @Dims - A HTTPS is built upon trust.  Google goes to a CA that your browser by default trusts, they purchase a certificate signed by that CA, thus any certificate purchased and presented by Google is trusted by your browser.  Kaspersky purchased a certificate, they on the fly generate certificates, for a site.  Your browser trusts these certificates because Kaspersky  placed them in your certificate store, Kaspersky is able to scan HTTPS traffic because ALL traffic is going through KIS instead of going directly to your browser.  **Basic HTTPS 101.**

Comment: Feel free to come into the chat to discus this topic.  I still maintain your goals are unrealistic if you want to keep that spy feature enabled.  I call it a spy because, in the wrong hands, that exactly what could be done.  Yes; It protects your secure http traffic, there are better ways like simply blocking known sources of those malicious content.

Comment: @Ramhound so you mean, that until Kaspersky is sending certificates on the fly, I has only two options: either trust them and then I will be able to browse sites, or not trust them, and I will see connection is compromised, but I can't close the traffic. And this is the general property of HTTPs?

Comment: @Dims, yes, those are your two options (three if you include the option of disabling this feature).  KIS is acting as a man-in-the-middle, intercepting all of your traffic.  So, if you want to have the feature enabled you must trust them because they have access to all of your traffic.

Comment: Come into chat, answers to your questions, is polluting the comments section.