# How to untrust proxy or antivirus certificate and/or certificate authority?

Tags: security, proxy, ssl, certificate, https

I have antivirus inspecting my web traffic including HTTPs.

[In this question](https://superuser.com/questions/974005/how-can-kaspersky-embed-code-into-web-page-accessed-via-https) we discovered, that it installed it's self certificates or certificate authority (not sure about terminology).

Now I wish to know, is it possible, to disable this authority by the means of the operating system, not by the means of antivirus program itself.

I opened MMC with Certificates snap-in and tried to drag some certificates from `Trusted` to `Untrusted` folder:

[image]

Immediately after this I checked and found, that AV is still able to change https traffic.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Drag and Drop, doing so, will cause a SSL error and ALL HTTPS connections so it really is a horrible idea

Comment: Please, suggest another option. The goal is to make connection private, not break it.

Comment: There isn't another option, you CANNOT make the connection private, if the KIS spy option is enabled

Comment: Why? How can they break HTTPs?

Comment: Because you installed a CA signed by Kaspersky, and indicated that all HTTPS traffic should be "scanned" by KIS, then presented to our browser. How they can break it, is because you enabled the option, to break it.

Comment: Probably, only by uninstalling Kaspersky, you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order for any HTTPS filter to work on content it must decrypt, filter, and then re-encrypt the data, since you do not have the private key for all the SSLs in use (rendering then worthless) your antivirus must encrypt the SSL on the fly with a new intermediate cert.

So in other words, your antivirus is a man in the middle... Filter.